# Why don't find and locate search /bin?

Tags: find, locate

What gives? Normal `find` and `locate` commands don't turn up the verify program that lives at `/bin/verify`. In fact, it seems they don't turn up anything that lives in `/bin`

```
[jake@jace]/bin% "find" /bin/ -iname "verify" 2>/dev/null
/bin/verify
[jake@jace]/bin% "find" /bin -iname "verify" 2>/dev/null 
[jake@jace]/bin% "find" / -iname "verify" 2>/dev/null 
/home/jake/android/cts/tools/vm-tests-tf/src/dot/junit/verify
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify
/usr/bin/verify
```

.

```
[jake@jace]/bin% locate "verify" | grep "bin"
/usr/bin/db_log_verify
/usr/bin/db_verify
/usr/bin/fprintd-verify
/usr/bin/json_verify
/usr/bin/ldns-verify-zone
/usr/bin/rpmverify
/usr/bin/verify
/usr/bin/verifytree
```

.

```
[jake@jace]/bin% "ls" -lh /bin/verify
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 32K May 22  2012 /bin/verify
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you quoting the command names?

Comment: @EvanTeitelman I alias a lot of commands. Quotes strip the aliasing. Eg, locate and grep (forgot to quote) are aliased to `"locate" -i` and `"grep" -i --color=auto`

Comment: You can prepend your commands with backslashes instead: `\ls -lh /bin/verify`.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman neat. is that posix? or just bash?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162903/temporarily-disabling-an-alias-quoting-a-word-with-a-backslash), the backslash just escapes the first character of the word, which causes the entire word to be considered "quoted" for the purposes of function calls and alias expansion. Words are not expanded as aliases if they are quoted. You could do `''ls`, `l''s`, or `""ls` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gah.

```
[jake@jace]/bin% ls -lhd /bin
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 May 22  2012 /bin -> usr/bin/
```

I'm running Fedora 17. Apparently `/bin` is symlinked to `/usr/bin`. And of course (and quite rightly) `find` and `locate` ignore symlinked directories to avoid result pollution.

Comment: Some [background](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge).

Comment: @JoelDavis The site doesn't let you accept your own answer right away. I will as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use for env [command]

```
env verify
```

Is one way to invoke a command when you do not know where it is.

BTW: /bin is a symlink on a lot of systems , Solaris for example.